# Pretty hg branch graphs

Tags: command-line, mercurial, branch

With hg, how I can see in command line the branches graphs? Similar to

```
git log --pretty=oneline --graph
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For `Mercurial 2.3` and up, use

```
hg log -G
```

For older Mercurial, you need to first install the the [graphlog extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GraphlogExtension) which will enable the above command. The graphlog extension also adds an alias

```
hg glog
```

in all versions of Mercurial.

Comment: Then you can just type, `hg glog` to get a similar output.

Answer (score 6):

You can create custom templates and aliases in hg. For instance, create an alias in your `.hgrc` as follows:

```
[alias]
lg = log --template "{label('custom.rev', rev)}\t{label('custom.phase',phase)}\t{label('custom.tag',tags)}\t{desc|firstline} {label('custom.age', date|age)} {label('custom.user', author|user)}\n"

[color]
custom.rev = yellow
custom.phase = bold
custom.user = cyan
custom.age = bold
custom.tag = bold yellow
```

and invoke it with

`hg lg -G`

The output will be like this.

[image]

Jordi has some awesome aliases in his [blog](http://jordi.inversethought.com/blog/customising-mercurial-like-a-pro/)

Comment: Any idea how can i make it look like a graph ? it always shows a single timeline of the current branch. I tried following the instructions on Jordis blog and it's not working

Comment: @danfromisrael In case interested, look at my .hgrc is here https://bitbucket.org/carun/dot-files/raw/tip/.hgrc

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Here is a graph of Kallithea repo: http://i.imgur.com/sYieqUF.png My `~/.hgrc` alias has `lg = log --template "{label('custom.rev', rev)}\t{label('custom.node',node|short)} {label('custom.phase',phase)} \t{label('custom.age',date|age)}\t{desc|firstline} {label('custom.user', author|user)} {label('custom.branch',branch)} {label('custom.tag',tags)} {label('custom.book',bookmarks)}\n" -G` I also have `[experimental] graphshorten = true`